# Staled sessions with `null` principal name in Spring Session Redis Index

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I'm storing sessions in Redis using spring-boot and spring-session-redis.

I have the following use-case.
When a user lands at `/admin`, Spring Boot generates an anonymous session for such user and redirects him to the login page.

When a user passes authentication process, `RedisIndexedSessionRepository` persists the session identifier in the index under `session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:null` key, and this index never cleanup.

I believe this leads to a memory leak.
What should I do to avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1987

I provided an explanation and fix in the PR: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/1988